# How do I publish my API folder with the rest of my MVC website in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have an "API" folder in the root of my web project, and I can't seem to find any project deployment settings that automatically publish the API folder along with the rest of the website.

Is there such a thing, or am I forced to manually use the "Publish API" context menu?

[image: MVC project with API folder]